# Statistic is not complete: uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, uniform-distribution

How can one proove, that $X$, which is uniformly distributed on the interval $(\theta, \theta+1), \theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is not complete for $\theta$?

I have to find a function, such that $E_{\theta}[h(T)] = 0$ where $h(t) \neq 0$ right? Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm interpreting it right, then $X \sim \mathcal{U}(\theta,\theta+1)$ and the statistic we're considering is $T(X) = X$.

Note that $E[h(T(X)); \theta] =E[h(X);\theta]= \int_\theta^{\theta+1} h(x) \; dx$. Just need $h$ to integrate to zero over this region (and not be zero itself!). Think trigonometric functions . . .

Comment: I know, and thats the problem, I don't know how to find or start to find such a function...

Comment: Oh sorry - to be specific try the sine function with period 1 (instead of the usual $2\pi$). Then since you're integrating over $[\theta,\theta+1]$ an interval of length one, it'll zero out